# Scroll View not working on android pixel simulator, but its working on ios devices and simulator

Tags: android, css, react-native, flexbox

````
    return (
    <View style={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        flex: 1,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    }}> 
    <ScrollView horizontal={false} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} >

        {<View style={{
            flex: 1
        }}>
            <LocationPicker navigation={this.props.navigation} onLocationPicked={this.locationPickedHandler}/>
        </View>}
        </ScrollView>
    </View>);```
````

I have tried setting height, flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 everything but hard luck

Can anyone please help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

React native ScrollView has a horizontal property that arranges its children in a row when set to true.

```
   return (
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    }}> 
    <ScrollView horizontal={false} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} >

        <View style={{
            flex: 1
        }}>
            <LocationPicker navigation={this.props.navigation} onLocationPicked={this.locationPickedHandler}/>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>);
```